# UIScrollView not show image on iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I've a problem with `UIScrollView`. It works perfectly on previous iOS version but not on iOS9.

Here is my code

```
ProductHeaderCV *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:
                                       UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderCV" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        headerView.delegate = self;
        headerView.catNameLabel.font  = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_PSL size:14.0];
        headerView.sortNameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_PSL size:14.0];

        //ScrollView
        [headerView.pageControl setNumberOfPages:[specialCateArray count]];
        headerView.pageControlScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*[specialCateArray count], 180);
        headerView.pageControlScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        float originX = 0;

        for(NSDictionary *dict in specialCateArray){
            NSString *img = [dict objectForKey:@"image"];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(originX, 0, 320, 180)];
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:img] placeholderImage:nil];

            originX = originX+320;
            [headerView.pageControlScrollView addSubview:imageView];
        }
```

One more weird thing I've used the same code above and add it as subview on self `UIScrollView` (MainViewController) It's working without any problem.

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: could you be more precise with your question? like what exactly is your problem.

Comment: headerView.pageControlScrollView is UIScrollView from another xib and I'm trying to add image into that ScrollView but when I run this code nothing show up on the screen.